# Vue JS, Axios retry request. Prevent JSON quotes

Tags: json, vue.js, axios, interceptor

I have an axios interceptor for cases, where I need the user to be authorized, but he isn't. For example, because the token is expired.
Now, after a token refresh, the original request should be retried.
However, currently the original requests, seems to be changed, so that the Server gives me a JSON.parse error.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/var/app/current/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:158:10)
    at parse (/var/app/current/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /var/app/current/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/var/app/current/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/var/app/current/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/var/app/current/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)
```

This is because, instead of the original request, that is JSON, it seems to process it again, puts it in quotes etc., so it becomes a string and the bodyparser, throws the error above.
So the request content, becomes:

```
"{\"traderaccount\":\"{\\\"traderaccountID\\\":\\\"undefined\\\",\\\"traderID\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"Conscientious\\\",\\\"order\\\":99,\\\"myFxLink\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"myFxWidget\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"copyFxLink\\\":\\\"83809\\\",\\\"tokenLink\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"tradertext\\\":{\\\"tradertextID\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"traderaccountID\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"language\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"commission\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"affiliateSystem\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"leverage\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"mode\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"description\\\":\\\"\\\"},\\\"accountType\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"accountTypeID\\\":1,\\\"minInvest\\\":2000,\\\"currency\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"currencySymbol\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"currencyID\\\":1,\\\"affiliateSystem\\\":1}\"}"
```

instead of

```
{"traderaccount":"{\"traderaccountID\":\"undefined\",\"traderID\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Conscientious\",\"order\":99,\"myFxLink\":\"\",\"myFxWidget\":\"\",\"copyFxLink\":\"83809\",\"tokenLink\":\"\",\"tradertext\":{\"tradertextID\":\"\",\"traderaccountID\":\"\",\"language\":\"\",\"commission\":\"\",\"affiliateSystem\":\"\",\"leverage\":\"\",\"mode\":\"\",\"description\":\"\"},\"accountType\":\"\",\"accountTypeID\":1,\"minInvest\":2000,\"currency\":\"\",\"currencySymbol\":\"\",\"currencyID\":1,\"affiliateSystem\":1}"}
```

from the original axios request content.
Both are the unformated request contents, that I can see in the developer network console.

The content type, is application/json in both cases.

Below is the Interceptor code:

```
    Axios.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => {
        return response;
      },
      (err) => {
        const error = err.response;
        if (
          error !== undefined &&
          error.status === 401 &&
          error.config &&
          !error.config.__isRetryRequest
        ) {
          if (this.$store.state.refreshToken === "") {
            return Promise.reject(error);
          }
          return this.getAuthToken().then(() => {
            const request = error.config;
            request.headers.Authorization =
              Axios.defaults.headers.common[globals.AXIOSAuthorization];
            request.__isRetryRequest = true;
            return Axios.request(request);
          });
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
```

```
  private getAuthToken() {
    if (!this.currentRequest) {
      this.currentRequest = this.$store.dispatch("refreshToken");
      this.currentRequest.then(
        this.resetAuthTokenRequest,
        this.resetAuthTokenRequest
      );
    }
    return this.currentRequest;
  }

  private resetAuthTokenRequest() {
    this.currentRequest = null;
  }

// store refreshToken
    async refreshToken({ commit }) {
      const userID = this.state.userID;
      const refreshToken = Vue.prototype.$cookies.get("refreshToken");
      this.commit("refreshLicense");
      commit("authRequest");
      try {
        const resp = await axios.post(serverURL + "/refreshToken", {
          userID,
          refreshToken,
        });
        if (resp.status === 200) {
          return;
        } else if (resp.status === 201) {
          const token = resp.data.newToken;
          const newRefreshToken = resp.data.newRefreshToken;
          Vue.$cookies.set(
            "token",
            token,
            "14d",
            undefined,
            undefined,
            process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
            "Strict"
          );
          Vue.$cookies.set(
            "refreshToken",
            newRefreshToken,
            "30d",
            undefined,
            undefined,
            process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
            "Strict"
          );
          axios.defaults.headers.common[globals.AXIOSAuthorization] = token;
          commit("authSuccessRefresh", { newRefreshToken });
        } else {
          this.dispatch("logout");
          router.push({
            name: "login",
          });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        commit("authError");
        this.dispatch("logout");
      }
```

So, can you help me to prevent Axios on the retried request to change the request content. So it doesn't put it into quotes and quote the already exisitng quotes?

Comment: Why was the interceptor posted? Are there reasons to consider it the source of the problem? Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem . It's unknown what happens with getAuthToken. But this part looks fishy `const request = error.config`. You shouldn't reuse the object, instead clone it. The thing that could possibly happen there is that `request.data` has been already stringified. In this case you need to JSON.parse it during cloning. If you believe the problem is there then you need to inspect it, and currently only you can do this

Comment: Yay, I think it has to do with the interceptor, because the 401 gets intercepted, and then retried. And the retried request is the problematic one.
I think, you are on the right track, that the request.data is already stringified and that it does it again on Axios.request(request).
Why can't I use the const request = error config? I have seen interceptor implementations, where error.config was used directly for the Axios.request. Isn't that the original request, that I want to retry? Is a clone really necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment I found a solution.
Try to parse the content before resending it:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
 (response) => response,
 (error) => {
 const status = error.response ? error.response.status : null;

 if (status === 401 && error.config && !error.config.__isRetryRequest) {
  return refreshToken(useStore()).then(() => {
    const request = error.config;
    request.headers.Authorization =
      axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];
    request.__isRetryRequest = true;
    try {
      const o = JSON.parse(request.data);

      if (o && typeof o === "object") {
        request.data = o;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return axios.request(request);
    }
    return axios.request(request);
  });
 }

 return Promise.reject(error);
});
```